# Getting exception when locking a user in WSO2

Tags: wso2, locking, wso2-identity-server

I am getting an exception when locking user. I've added **org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock-1.4.17-SNAPSHOT.jar** file to components/dropins without any changes,it was first try of handler testing. Are there any ideas of fixing it?

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-27 13:23:53,027] [422b2bd0-051a-4070-9a07-3f9b62f6dabc] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver} - org/wso2/carbon/identity/governance/IdentityMgtConstants$LockedReason java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/identity/governance/IdentityMgtConstants$LockedReason
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler.handlePostSetUserClaimValues(AccountLockHandler.java:562)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler.handleEvent(AccountLockHandler.java:198)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.services.IdentityEventServiceImpl.handleEvent(IdentityEventServiceImpl.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:1642)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:1618)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:1606)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.doPostSetUserClaimValues(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:168)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4044)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler.setUserClaim(AccountLockHandler.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler.handlePostSetUserClaimValues(AccountLockHandler.java:545)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler.handleEvent(AccountLockHandler.java:180)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.services.IdentityEventServiceImpl.handleEvent(IdentityEventServiceImpl.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:1642)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:1618)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.handleEvent(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:1606)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance.listener.IdentityMgtEventListener.doPostSetUserClaimValues(IdentityMgtEventListener.java:168)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4044)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.mgt.UserProfileAdmin.setUserProfile(UserProfileAdmin.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:170)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub.UserProfileMgtServiceStub.setUserProfile(UserProfileMgtServiceStub.java:529)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient.setUserProfile(UserProfileCient.java:68)
    at org.apache.jsp.userprofile.edit_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(edit_002dfinish_002dajaxprocessor_jsp.java:268)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

TID: [-1234] [] [2021-01-27 13:23:53,041] [422b2bd0-051a-4070-9a07-3f9b62f6dabc] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} - org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org/wso2/carbon/identity/governance/IdentityMgtConstants$LockedReason
```

Comment: Do you want to update the logic in org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock and test ?

Comment: And what is the version of IS do you use?

Comment: @AnuradhaKarunarathna 5.10.0. I am trying to add some logic, so i can send locked,unlocked usernames to my backend and update user information in my local database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock` jar file is packed in the identity server product in `<IS-HOME>/repository/components/plugins`. If you want to do any update on that, you need to follow the patching process.

1. Find out the version of the plugin at `<IS-HOME>/repository/components/plugins`
2. Checkout that particular version from the source code.
   For example : org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock_1.4.0.jar is available in IS-5.10.0,so you need to get tag v1.4.0 https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/tree/v1.4.0, and do the changes on it. Then build the component.
3. Navigate to the `<IS-HOME>/repository/components/patches` folder. Create a folder named `patch9999` and add the jar file there. Then start the server.

The runtime issue you have encountered here is due to using the latest version. It contains the fix https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/pull/84 which depends on some other components.

Comment: I've updated successfully,but how i can log my patch,is it similar to components/dropins? (create logger in log4j.properties file and add it to loggers=)?

Comment: Are there another ways of connecting/synchronizing data in wso2 and my local database?

Comment: Cannot set true **account.lock.handler.enable=false**  in my identity/identity-event file,or it should work by default?

Comment: Try again by adding ```[identity_mgt.events.schemes.'account.lock.handler']
properties.enable=true``` into the deployment toml and restart

Comment: ```java  loggers = AUDIT_LOG,AccountLockHandler,trace-messages..

logger.AccountLockHandler.name = org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock.AccountLockHandler
logger.AccountLockHandler.level = ALL 
logger.AccountLockHandler.appenderRef.CARBON_LOGFILE.ref = CARBON_LOGFILE 
logger.AccountLockHandler.additivity = false
```

Comment: added my jar to patches/patch9999 (updated successfully), but not logging any information

Comment: account.lock.handler.enable=true settled to true afer adding [identity_mgt.events.schemes.'account.lock.handler'] properties.enable=true